# Actions On Google: Implicit Oauth Flow, redirect fails

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, implicit-flow

I implemented my own Oauth server for the implicit flow, following the instructions of: https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2?oauth=implicit

It seems quick simple as I just need to redirect the token after checking client details. But there is where I got the issue. 
I am sending this:
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&state=STATE_STRING

However, when you redirect to this URL, this seems to mess up actions on google. The "Sing in Helper" intent seems to work and then fails, the console does not show any error [Intent not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hPX0.png)

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the ? in the url to a #.
This will then use fragmentation in the url which will allow google to read the parameters.

https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/YOUR_PROJECT_ID#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&state=STATE_STRING

Comment: I had the same issue a few days ago and this seemed to fix it